# How do I get WebStorm to format each function call argument on its own line, aligned to the opening parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, code-formatting

Current when WebStorm formats my javascript code it makes it look like this:

```
this.someThing = new namespace.UsefulClass(veryLongArgumentOne,
    veryLongArgumentTwo,
    shortArgument,
    3);
```

What I am trying to get it do is this:

```
this.someThing = new namespace.UsefulClass(veryLongArgumentOne,
                                           veryLongArgumentTwo,
                                           shortArgument,
                                           3);
```

That is I want each argument on its own line, but aligned with the opening parenthesis rather than indented one additional step.

WebStorm has a code style dialog with lots of options, and I have set it to break on long lines, but I can't find the option to align them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Javascript -> Wrapping and Braces -> Function call arguments -> Align when multiline